# using the same aggregate function in the same having clause mutliple times

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I am trying to filter data I get from a group by query using "having". For this I need to use the same aggregate function (min(x) and max(x)) multiple times in the having clause. This does not work, I get an error message

"Orig exception: Code: 184, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Aggregate function min(strike) is found inside another aggregate function in query, e.what() = DB::Exception"

I tried to define the min and max in the select clause at the top as min_strike and max_strike and use it in the having clause. This does also not work.

Edit: Edited the code, forgot to add the condition.

```
select 
      <<structureid and some other variables>>
  from
      <<a huge query, including multiple joins>>
 group by structureid
having min(strike)!=max(strike) 
   and sumIf(notional,strike=min(strike))>0
```

The idea is to apply the filters exactly at that point where its grouped.

For example:

```
   structure id     |      strike       |         notional

     1              |        1.10       |           10
     1              |        1.12       |          -10
     2              |        1.10       |          -10
     2              |        1.12       |           10
     3              |        1.10       |          -10
     3              |        1.10       |           10
```

In this case, I want to filter out structureid=2 and only select structureid=1, so that my result table would look like this:

```
   structure id     |      min strike       |         max strike

     1              |        1.10           |           1.12
```

Edit: I am doing it with some kind of "self join" now, which does not seem to be implemented in clickhouse either, so I end up doing

```
  <<a huge query, including multiple joins>>
```

twice. One of those tables I group by structure id and calculate all the aggregate values. The other is not grouped. I then join them via structureid (using 'all inner join') and I apply my filter on the combined table:

```
select final variables
(
select 
      <<a lot of unaggregated variables>>
  from
      <<a huge query, including multiple joins>>
 group by structureid
 )
 all inner join
(
select 
      <<min(strike) as min_strike, max(strike) as max_strike, and other 
  aggregate variables>>
  from
      <<a huge query, including multiple joins>>
 group by structureid
 )
 using structureid
 where min_strike!=max_strike and (notional>0 and strike=min_strike)
```

This seems extremely inefficient. But I cannot think of another solution. Any idea how to implement this better would be very much appreciated!

Comment: The problem isnt using the aggregated function multiple times. The problem is the nested aggregated functions. We need some data and expected output to see how we can help you to rewrite the query

Comment: what do  `sumIf(notional,strike=min(strike))` ?? doesnt looks like a condition for the having

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I edited my initial question. How can I add data to clarify my problem?

Comment: In most databases, you would use window functions for this purpose.  I don't think that Clickhouse supports them.

Comment: What about structure id=3 and "filter out" based on what?

Comment: Here's the thread to follow for window functions support btw https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/issues/1469

Comment: structureid=3 is filtered out because min_strike=max_strike.

Comment: I edited my initial post with the workaround solution I am implementing now. I am very unhappy with this, as I am afraid it is extremely inefficient.